# Need suggestion parsing different csv files and saving to the database

Tags: c#, parsing, csv

This may be simple for some of you, and maybe a bit confusing to explain, but here it goes.

I have three different csv files that is generated by the system of the previous day's phone calls. The csv files are not very well created. Following are the comma separated values in the files.

First file: 
`* For calls connected to agents.  ** Including calls aborted and rejected.,Application Summary Analysis,1/15/2015 8:30:00 AM(-5:00),-,1/15/2015 9:00:00 PM(-5:00),Application Name,Called Number,CallsPresented,Flow-In,Flow-Out,CallsHandled,AvgSpeed ofAnswer*,AvgTalk Time*,Avg Work Time*,Calls Abandoned**,AvgAbandonTime,ABCD,12345,928,0,0,833,0:00:36,0:01:45,0:00:23,95,0:01:07,,,Report generated:,1/23/2015, 6:00:38PM,(30280),1`

This is in one single line.

The second one is: 
`* Calls handled by workflow script or another CSQ.,Contact Service Queue Activity Report,1/15/2015 8:30:00 AM(-5:00),-,1/15/2015 9:00:00 PM(-5:00),CSQ Name (ID)(Call Skills),CallsPresented,Avg / MaxQueue Time,CallsHandled,Avg Speedof Answer,Avg / MaxHandle Time,CallsAbandoned,Avg / MaxTime toAbandon,Avg / MaxAbandonPer Day,CallsDequeued,Avg / MaxTime toDequeue,Calls Handledby Other *,Program1,435,0:00:37,422,0:00:37,0:02:18,13,0:01:06,6.50,0,0:00:00,0,Program1,0:06:46,0:12:01,0:06:18,13,0:00:00,,,Report generated:,1/23/2015, 6:00:37PM,(12345),1`

But there are three lines of similar data for other programs.

And similarly there's another csv file with similar format as the one above with three lines for three different programs.

I need to parse these files and save it in the database. I understand this is poorly created csv, but this is how Cisco generated it.

The way I currently have done is read the file using `StreamReader` and saved the parsed data in `IEnumerable`. I then iterate through the list and extract the data at specified position and saved it in the class property. I created 3 classes for each CSV file types with properties similar to the what supposed to be header in the CSV files, and saved the extracted data in the property. This was then saved in the database using DbContext. Is there a better way to do this? May be create a generic type and then save the extracted data and save it? Or is it too vague? I'm not very experience in this, so, how would an experienced programmer solve this problem? BTW, I'm using C# and storing in SQL Server 2008

Comment: Worth asking - are you sure there are no line breaks?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure, and I have opened the file several times hoping of different outcome, LOL. But it's always in the same line - header and the data both. It's really strange the way they created their CSV.

Comment: What do you use to "open" the file? I'm only asking because this could help - e.g. without getting too complicated, use something like Notepad++ and view all characters just to make sure its not a matter of [different systems' way of terminating/ending lines](http://superuser.com/questions/362087/notepad-ignoring-linebreaks).

Comment: I'm reading the line using StreamReader in C#. I read the data specifying the field position. I was just wondering if there's a better way to more generalize this process than providing field position for different csv files.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly SQL Server has a very powerful data loading facility built right into it, but its been a while since I used it. I would recommend looking into this. Also, what is your end goal? That might help. I see your skill set is sql server and c# - that's why I mentioned the data loading facility in sql server.

Comment: Well, the end goal is to display it on an intranet site, and also save it in excel using a template and distribute it to the contractor. I already have a site built using web api which displays the data in certain way that is required by the business. But to your suggestion, how would SQL Server would handle this? The CSV file doesn't separate the headers from the data like most other properly created csv files. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

If the data in each line in uniform (meaning each line has same columns). Something like this

```
col1, col2, col3, col4
col1, col2, col3, col4
col1, col2, col3, col4
```

Then you may use something like this

```
BULK INSERT TableName FROM 'c:\mycsvfile.txt'
WITH   (  FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'   )
```

of course table `TableName` contains  col1, col2, col3, col4 (in that sequence).

Comment: I don't know if this can help. In the first csv file, the elements from 6 to 16 are the headers, and elements from 17 to 27 are the data. The remaining are useless, except for the dates in elements at 3 and 5.

Comment: Perhaps you can parse and  copy data to be saved in DB into another csv file and then bulk insert.

Comment: Hmm.. so in a way, not much different than what I already did. I was just hoping to have a better - reusable and scalable way for this. We never know when Cisco might push an update and change the file or the data location in the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a macro in excel to accomplish preprocessing the headers, then it will be in excel and ready to import into the database